# Script Search users outlook autocomplete

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, outlook

Currently I need to loop through all Users on a computer to check if their Outlook autocomplete file contains a certain display name and delete it.
The script will be tested through windows Powershell ISE.
and the script will be a batch file, running a txt file through NK2Edit.
I got the script to run for a specific user and a specific auto completefile
you can see tools and tutorials I used here:

[NK2Edit Script](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/edit_nk2_script.html/)

As well as the changes Outlook auto complete files here:

[Outlook Auto Complete file differences](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nk2_file_location.html)

I am using the 2010 Outlook model so the file will be different for every user
unlike the older versions that used the profile name with a NK2 at the end.
Here are the commands I am running

C:\Users\name\Desktop\NK2EditTest\NK2Edit.exe /script "C:\Users\name\Desktop\NK2EditTest\remove-old-support.txt" "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache\Stream_Autocomplete_X_XXXXXXXX.dat"
while X's represent the random 16 byte key in hexadecimal format.

**MY Question:**
How can I specify Stream_Autocomplete_X_XXXXX...dat files for multiple users
without hard coding it for every user?

Comment: "Currently I need to loop through all Users on a computer to check if their Outlook autocomplete file contains a certain display name and delete it." Why?

Comment: At my work we have control of hundreds of users accounts. I am familiar with some coding and commands but not Admin level scripting on a large scale. Im also trying to find a way to iterate through these users but I wanted to take this one problem at a time =) right now I'm focused on seeing if I could run a command in this format to check if something is a dat file and contains the string "Stream_Autocomplete_" This is only my theory of how to do it. but I haven't found anything on this. not even the NK2Edit site.

Comment: But what problem are you trying to fix? (Tell _what_ you want to do, not _how_ you think it needs to be done.)

Comment: The client has an outdated email saved on their auto complete. And should not be sending emails to that email anymore because it is used for something else now. The users that still have it sometimes still send it to that email when it shows up on their auto complete. It seems like a silly task but is important for what we need.

Comment: I tried implementing a command in the batch file you see up there. "It contains Stream_Autocomplete_" after RoamCache\ but It didn't go through because it is part of the command for NK2Edit. Im wondering if I could find the string ahead of time maybe. and see if its a dat file, because there are also bak files with the same name. and then put that path in my command I have above.

Comment: I was able to accomplish deleting the saved name using the command, If DisplayName equal "support@emailName.com" Delete, this is described in the links above if you'd like to see

Comment: @AntonioGarcia, could you please put all these extra information into the question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41384570/edit) your post?

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking how to execute the program nk2edit.exe using relative paths for both the executable itself as well as its configuration files. One solution is to place nk2edit.exe as a file in a GPO user logon script and reference the configuration files relative to the executing script. For example (not tested):

```
# Get path of currently executing PowerShell script
$scriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
# Form path to nk2edit.exe (must sit in same directory as PowerShell script)
$nk2edit = Join-Path $scriptPath "nk2edit.exe"
# Form path to nk2edit.exe script (must sit in same directory as PowerShell script)
$scriptFile = Join-Path $scriptPath "remove-old-support.txt"
# Execute nk2edit.exe command for each Stream_AutoComplete_* for current user
Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $Env:LOCALAPPDATA "Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache\Stream_Autocomplete_*") | ForEach-Object {
  & $nk2edit /script $scriptFile $_.FullName
}
```